# Tracking using google analytics when customer redirects from my website to other website and Places an successful order

Tags: google-analytics, magento2

I have a magento store. There is a button on product Page which gives option to customer to buy the same product from another website.

If the user redirects from my store to other website, and buys product from other website, I want to track this using Google Analytics.

Being new to Google analytics, I don't know what's the best way to implement that functionality. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the click on the button to GO to the other website.

To measure if they buy something there you should add an event on the other website that send the ga data to your own UA id..

Comment: How do I combine the two events? Like goal is hit when both of this occur in a sequence.

Comment: Well , if you do have access to both websites, on the first you could send an event to your UA account named for example buttonClicked and on the second for example productBought you have 2 events, problem with GA is that events can't be placed in a funnel to achieve a goal , so you could convert them in tag manager (or hardcoded ga) to a virtual pageview. That way you can build a funnel

Comment: Please elaborate how I can accomplish `so you could convert them in tag manager (or hardcoded ga) to a virtual pageview.`

Comment: https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/09/10/fire-virtual-pageview-google-tag-manager/